# Getting error "Process cannot access file" while deleting file in Python

Tags: python, delete-file

I am working on a project where I have many json files stored in a directory. I need to read all the files and check there data. If 'session`is`false` in any of the files, I need to delete the file. Below is the code:

```
files = os.listdir(config_files_path)
for file in files:
    file_path = config_files_path + '//' + file
    f = open(file_path)

    data = json.load(f)

    if not data['session']:
        # delete this file
        os.remove(file_path)
```

In the above code, I am getting the list of all the files. Then iterating over each file and reading its content in `data`. `if not data['session']`,  I need to delete that file. But doing so I am getting `process cannot access the file as its being used by another process`. Is there any way we can delete the file. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised because the file is still open. You must close it before trying to delete it. So, after you have loaded the data, do `f.close()`. Like this:

```py
files = os.listdir(config_files_path)
for file in files:
    file_path = config_files_path + '//' + file

    f = open(file_path)
    data = json.load(f)
    f.close()  # <-- close the file

    if not data['session']:
        # delete this file
        os.remove(file_path)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to close the file before deleting it.
 Use f.close() before os.remove(file_path) statement